# How to get the string version of a variable that uses the function parameter in Python?

Tags: python

Might be a dumb question, but I have a variable in my function that uses the parameter of the function. I would like to get the string version of that. I cannot figure out how to turn it into a string. For example, in this code:

```
def f(x):
    ans = 2*x**2+3*x
    return ans
```

How can I get ans just as a string, still retaining the x's in it? I have tried passing 'x', but it throws an error because it tries to multiply a string. I have tried printing it before x is given as a parameter but that doesn't work because ans is defined by the parameter. Anyone have suggestions?

Comment: https://github.com/sympy/sympy is a library for doing such a thing

Comment: Fantastic, it was as simple as using sympy symbols. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: an alternative though not recommended way is to use `eval`. Put your ans as a string i.e. `ans = "2*x**2+3*x"`, and then `return f"{ans}={eval(ans)}"`.

Comment: have you tried str(ans)?